# Unable to understand option 2 of this question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Let $A$ and $B$ be events satisfying $P(A∩B)$ = $P(A)$ + $P(B)$.

Which of the following statements is/are true?

1. If $A$≠ $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A) = 0 $ or $P(B) = 0$.
3. If $P(A) > P(B) > 0$, then $A$ and $B$ are not independent.
4. If $A$ = $S$, the sample space, then $P(B) = 0$.

---

By process of elimination:

Option $1$ is correct since if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, $P(A ∩ B) = 0$.

Option $3$ is correct as if $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)>0$, $P(A)*P(B)>0$ meaning $P(A ∩ B) >0$. This is a contradiction thus not independent.

Option $4$ is correct as $P(B) > 0$ the initial statement given would be false.

Option $2$ is the one I'm having difficulty understanding, is it vacuously true(is logic language even used here or is it a normal if-then statement?) since it's established that $A$ and $B$ are exclusive?

Comment: As in general $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap )B$, that is $P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap )B$ we get $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap )B$, that is $P(A\cup B)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for (2): The given equation gives $(1-P(A)) (1-P(B))=1$. If either $P(A) \neq 0$ or $P(B) \neq 0$ then the left is a product of two numbers one of which is less than $1$ and the other $\leq 1$ leading to a contradiction. Hence we must have $P(A)=P(B)=0$.

Comment: Oh, so in this case both $P(A)=P(B)=0$ and not just 1 of them? This seems to imply option 2 is wrong?

Comment: Yes, $P(A)=P(B)=0$ but this does not imply that option 2 is wrong. Because in math, "or" means "inclusive or". If statements S,T are both true then "S or T" is true too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like an exercise to check the knowledge of definitions. I hope I am using the same definitions as you.

*Option 1*
Firstly, I believe that your argument for option 1 is not valid. Events are *mutually exclusive* if the intersection of both of them (as a subset of your probability space)  is empty. This indeed implies $P(A\cap B)=0$. But you need for your argument the opposite implication.

Now if you work over countable probability space, what I wrote in the previous paragraph is just some unnecessary technicality. But if you are in uncountable probability space things get more funnier.  Because intersection can be non-empty but still of measure zero.

*Option 2* This option is indeed correct. But I would not say it is *vacuously correct*. Though if you have a mutual exclusiveness it is indeed easy, because you have $0=P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

Without the assumption of mutual exclusiveness, you go by $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ by assumption of independence. Hence you have $ P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

Then you have two options. Firstly $P(A)=P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(B)$ this directly implies $P(B)=0$ and also $P(A)=0$.  Or $P(A)<P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(B)$ but this is contradiction.